# Rendering a partialview from within a helperclass in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, partial-views, umbraco7

I have some html that is used a lot in the site i'm building. So I created a App_Code\Helpers.cshtml file and placed the helperfunction in that file.

Now, I want to render a partial-view (a MVC view for a form). But I can't use `@Html.Partial("MyFormPartial", new formModel())`

I can't find any other ways of rendering a partial view from within a helper class. Anybody got an idea on how to solve this?

Is a seperate `helpers.cshtml` even the best way for this kind of repeating html-code? I think it gives me a bit more freedom in the parameters I'm providing, instead of the macro's. But it sucks I can't use `@Umbraco` (without creating your own helper) or `@Html` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `@Html` to the helper function if you don't want to create it inside the helper function.

Nevertheless, isn't it a better idea to use a [child action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/) and render part of code you'd like to been shared?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with childactions, but as far as I can tell it looks like a good solution. I will read the complete article right away.

For now (I needed a quick solution, and it's one single issue) I will pass the @html object. So simple, I didn't think of it at all.

Thank you!